# How to convert bulk of csv into json

Tags: python, json, csv

Below is the code to convert one csv file into json

List all the files in the dir

[data1.csv, data2.csv,data.csv]

Below is the code to convert one file to json. Like i need to loop all the files

```
import csv 
import json 
import os
import glob

os.chdir(r'dir' )
result = glob.glob( '*.csv' )
print (result) 
def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath): 
      
    for i in result:
        data = {} 
        with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
            csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
            for rows in csvReader: 
                key = rows['id'] 
                data[key] = rows 
        with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
            jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) 
        csvFilePath =f"{i}"
        jsonFilePath =f"{i.split('.')[-2]}.json"
make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

I have similar kind of files which need to convert into json. in every files `id` is the primary key

Lot of files are there. i dont want to change the csvFilePath and jsonFilePath  everytime.

The issue facing?

- My all json files is ending with `.csv.json`
- Last file name data9.csv is not converting to json and data2 is converting twice as data2.json and data2.csv.json

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 Lot of files are there. i dont want to change the csvFilePath and jsonFilePath  everytime

Comment: @WeavingBird1917, its not a typo instead it's a variable name.

Comment: To iterate over the files in the directory, you can use either the `os.listdir()` (current directory only) or `os.walk()` (recursive directories).

Comment: Can you clarify what is your question? If you can convert one file, what is stopping you from converting one file after the other? You apparently already know how to use a ``for`` loop, what trouble do you have looping over the file names to call ``make_json`` on each?

Comment: @Modelmat output is ending with .csv.json

Comment: @aysh So your actual question is "how to create a ``.json`` filename based on a ``.csv`` filename"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I put this question. if any one have better answers it would be good to refer

Comment: Take a look at the `str.replace()` function, you could replace the `.csv` part of the name with `.json`.

Comment: @Modelmat can you test once my code?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i have sorted out first issue, can you check second issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach,

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

for csv_f in glob.glob('/<file_path>/*.csv'):
    with open(f'{csv_f.replace(".csv", ".json")}', "w") as f:
        pd.read_csv(csv_f).set_index('id') \
            .to_json(f, orient='index')
```